# How to get data from the TreelView list

Tags: python, parsing, scrape, treelist

http://www.vliz.be/vmdcdata/mangroves/aphia.php?p=browser&id=235056&expand=true#ct
(That's the information I am trying to scrape)

**I wanna to scrape this detailed taxonomic trees so that I can manipulate them anyway I like.**

But there are a few problem in geting this tree data.

1. I can' t fully expand the taxonomic tree . when some expanding ,some collapse as the instruction indicated . 
   so saving the full page as html files can not sove my problem.
   or I can repeat the process some times to get separate files and concatenate them.. but it seems to be a ugly way.
2. I am tired of clicking , there are so many "plus" signs and I have to wait.

Is there a way to solve this out using **Python**  ?

Comment: hmm. using Chrome i can expand the entire tree, without branches closing. What lib are you using for scraping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Selenium`, this will expand the tree by clicking on the "plus signs" and get the entire DOM with all the elements in it after it's done:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

browser=webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('http://www.vliz.be/vmdcdata/mangroves/aphia.php?p=browser&id=235301&expand=true#ct')

while True:
      try:
          elem=browser.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@src="http://www.marinespecies.org/images/aphia/pnode.gif" or @src="http://www.marinespecies.org/images/aphia/plastnode.gif"]')[1]
          elem.click()
          time.sleep(2)
      except:
          break

content=browser.page_source
```

Comment: Thanks very much , I finally get  it done . I reused your code and parse the "content" variable using BeautifulSoup .